# JayData Phased Integration Into App

Tags: javascript, web-sql, jaydata

We're considering taking the plunge and porting our existing applications `WebSql` backend/data-layer over to `JayData`.  It's all client side.   We'd like to do the move in two stages allowing our application to continue to read from the database using existing methods, meanwhile our parsing would move over to allow JayData to control all the Reading/Writing data structures.

Early testing went very well.  `JayData` is a good ORM and easy to work with. However, we have come up against an error time and time again:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'initData' of undefined SqLiteProvider.min.js:35
DefaultError: DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK!

Exception {name: "DefaultError", message: "DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK!", data: Arguments[1], _getStackTrace: function}
```

According to the logs each stage of the parser (with JayData) completes successfully in its reading and writing.  The database however often has tables that haven't been populated.  All the tables are opened in the same context and controlled using `$.Deferreds.`

Is it a "false positive" that JayData thinks it has completed its transactions and the error is in fact telling me so?

Is it a problem to open the database (outside of JayData) and modify tables whilst the `context` is open (but not in use)?

**Update**

Following instructions from the comments.
The source is throwing the exception on *line 424* - `items[i].physicalData.initData = item.rows[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lengthy talk with the JayData team the problem was being caused by attempting to perform multiple operations on a context at one time.  The team suggested using a chain of promises operating on a shared context and then committing changes at the final stage.  This solved all my problems.

Comment: Hi CrimsonChin - I am having the same issue with JayData - I have narrowed it down and am quite confident I've got 2 saveChanges() trying to happen at the same time.
Do you have any links to a detailed explanation of "using a chain of promises operating on a shared context" that I could look at for an understanding to help me build my solution?

Comment: @user1290746 - Sorry, this was years ago and the source code is with the company I last worked for.  I'm a WPF developer these days and my JS has gone pretty rusty.

Comment: No worries - thank you for replying - I seem to have eliminated the issue now by having a single global object for doing the DB updates rather than having multiple instances of that object.

Answer (score 0):

We need more info, so:
- please use the not minified version so we can better locate the error
- if you use chrome then set it so it pauses on uncaught exceptions (purple sign) and when it stops look around, maybe something can be learnt there
- create a small example (preferably on jsfiddle) so we can debug it

Comment: Ok, for what its worth the error is happening on line 434 "items[i].physicalData.initData = item.rows[0];" I will try and get a fiddle worked out over the weekend.  It's an interesting problem because it seems to affect different operations at different times.

Comment: Hi @CrimsonChin, is the jsfiddle available? we would take a look into it.

Comment: @Robesz Hi, didn't get a chance to knock up a fiddle I'm afraid.  I can't get a good test case together.  Unfortunately deadlines are too tight at this stage in the project so we will be forced to sideline JayData for now.  Only short term. We'll be back!

Comment: Gabor Dolla & @Robesz I sent Gabor and email an email via the forum with access to our application to give you an example of the problem.  I hope it is of use.

Comment: We haven't received any e-mail yet. support{a}libraryname.org

Comment: @Robesz I had no idea you'd both replied, sorry.  The email went to Gabor's email (on the forum).  I'm fully concentrating on JayData for our application now so it's great to hear from you both.  If you need me to resend anything/everything please let me know

Comment: Hi! I support many users so I am not sure that which email you are referring. If I did not reply or the reply did not help then please send it again :)

Comment: Good morning, I sent another email to support@jaydata.org with all the details :)